# get_selected_rows from alv after handler PAI logic

Tags: abap, getselection, alv

I have an ALV in container on screen `0100`. It's created via class `CL_SALV_TABLE`.

The problem is that I can't get selected row via `go_alv_dms->get_selections( )->get_selected_rows( )` after pressing a button on the screen (2 on the screenshot).

I can access the selected rows with no problem if the button is in the ALV status bar (1 on the screenshot) though. It seems like pressing the button outside of ALV cleans selections of it.

[image]

Register selection when show ALV:

```
  ...
  lo_selections = go_alv_dms->get_selections( ).
  lo_selections->set_selection_mode( if_salv_c_selection_mode=>row_column ).
  lo_events = go_alv_dms->get_event( ).
  CREATE OBJECT go_handler.
  SET HANDLER go_handler->on_user_command2 FOR lo_events.
  ...
```

PAI of the screen button logic:

```
 go_handler->on_user_command2( gv_ok_0100 ).
```

Method `on_user_command2`:

```
    case gv_ok_0100.
      when 'OK'.
         ...
         lt_rows = go_alv_dms->get_selections( )->get_selected_rows( ).
         ...
    ENDCASE.
```

Comment: That should work like a charm. I don't understand your remark about "pressing the button outside of ALV [which works as you say] cleans selections", what does it bring to your question? (of course, getting the selected rows shouldn't unselect them). Did you reach your code when you press the buton in the ALV-owned toolbar? If no, then you didn't call cl_gui_cfw=>dispatch in the PAI. If yes, please provide a short standalone code so that we can copy it and reproduce your problem. (note that it's a matter of a 30-lines program to demonstrate that it should work "like a charm", as I said).

Comment: Yes, I reach my code when I press the buton in the ALV-owned toolbar. I added the code to the  question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After listening to the opinions of colleagues and searching for an answer on the Internet, I came to the conclusion that this is class `CL_SALV_TABLE` restriction. I rewrote the program on class `CL_ALV_GRID` and  it's earned. I like `CL_SALV_TABLE` and will be glad if someone refutes my statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
DATA gr_alv TYPE REF TO cl_salv_table.
DATA it_rows TYPE salv_t_row.
... 
gr_alv->get_metadata( ). " Call this method before getting selected rows
it_rows = gr_alv->get_selections( )->get_selected_rows( ).
```

Reference: https://answers.sap.com/questions/4693234/getselectedrows-returns-nothing.html